# Coldfusion/Railo: What's the most efficient way to output file contents - fileRead or include?

Tags: caching, coldfusion, railo

While I've always cached database calls and placed commonly used data into memory for faster access, I've been finding of late that simple processing and output of data can add a significant amount of time to page load and thus I've been working on a template caching component that will save parsed HTML to either a file, or in memory, for quicker inclusion on pages.

This is all working very well, reducing some page loads down to 10% of the uncached equivalent - however I find myself wondering what would be the most efficient way to output the content.

Currently I'm using `fileRead` to pull in the parsed HTML and save to a variable, which is output on the page.
This seems very fast, but I'm noticing the memory used by the Tomcat service gradually increasing - presumably because the `fileRead` operation is reading the contents into memory, and quite possibly, Tomcat isn't removing that data when its finished.

*(Side question: Anyone know a way that I can interrogate the JVM memory and find details/stack traces of the objects that CF has created??)*

Alternatively, I could use `cfinclude` to simply include the parsed HTML file. From all the information I can find it seems that the speed would be about the same - so would this method be more memory efficient?
I've had issues on the server before with memory usage crashing Tomcat, so keeping it down is quite important.

Is there anyone doing something similar that can give me the benefit of their experience?

Comment: If the heap is increasing and not going down, even after running a full GC, then take a heap dump to figure out what isn't being collected from the heap.

Comment: I'm not a Java developer, I've never been able to really get to grips with that - all the instructions I've found assume a lot of Java knowledge... and running Tomcat as a Windows service seems to make it very difficult to get a heap dump.

Comment: Railo lets you generate a heap dump via the cfadmin tag.  <cfadmin type="server" action="heapDump" destination="dump.prof">  There are several tools for analysing heap dumps such as the Eclipse Memory Analyizer Tool (MAT).  There are also CF tuning companies that can help you troubleshoot this if you need.

Comment: That is very useful information, thank you! I can't imagine why the heapdump action isn't listed in the docs for CFAdmin. Alas, without deep understanding of Railo's internals as a Java app, the information provided isn't a great deal of help to me... but it's very good to be able to get at it finally!

Comment: Railo has purposefully not documented cfadmin because they wish to eventually wrap it in an Admin CFC and the implementation may change at some point.  In the mean time, you have to just look at the code, or pay attention when they talk about it on their mailing list :)

Comment: Eventually being the operative word there I think! It's a shame... I don't mean to bury my head in the sand, but the increasingly common need for CF developers to know and understand Java is, to my mind, one of CF's major downfalls. Just my opinion, but to me it serves to create exclusivity for CF... a barrier to entry.

Comment: I am no so sure how much a heap dump helps. I would make sure that the CF is patched to run Java 7, and that I was on a recent release of 7, and that CF was using G1GC. G1GC is better at memory collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that CFInclude actually compiles the (already rendered in this case) content into a class, which itself has overhead. The classes aren't unloaded (according to CFTracker) and as such, too many of these can cause permgen errors. FileRead() seems to be orders of magnitude more efficient, as all we're doing is inserting content into the output buffer.

Answer (score 1):

cfinclude just includes the template into the one being compiled, whereas fileread has to read it into memory first and then output, so technically is going to consume more memory. I don;t expect the speed difference is much, but you can see the difference by just turning on debugging and checking the execution times.

Comment: Indeed, it seems the speed is pretty much identical - if the include method isn't going to increase memory in the same way fileRead does, I think this will be the way to go.

Comment: Just thought I'd come back here and update... It turns out that CFInclude actually compiles the (already rendered in this case) content into a class, which itself has overhead. The classes aren't unloaded (according to CFTracker) and as such, many of these can cause permgen errors. FileRead() seems to be orders of magnitude more efficient, as all we're doing is inserting content into the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to cached it with `cachePut()` and serve it from `cacheGet()`.  What can be faster than fetching from RAM?  Don't fetch it at all with proper Expire headers if it's the whole page, or smartly return 304 for Not Modified.

Comment: I seem to be having problems using EHCache on Railo... in any case I'd still want to be using files for storage as the server has had issues with memory and there are thousands of items to cache.

Comment: or try SSD then FileRead should be pretty fast.

Comment: I will be moving to SSD on this system shortly, but my issue is more about memory than speed really.

Comment: Railo has an extensible Cache infrastructure that allows you to cache items in an out-of-process location, thus keeping you from worrying about RAM. So you could go with Henry's cachePut() and cacheGet() idea, but point to an external cache.  This could be memcached, an external EHCache, or Couchbase cluster.   Disclaimer: I helped write a commercial extension to Railo for Couchbase.

Comment: @BradWood SSD vs extra hop to memcache or ehcache, which one would be faster you think?

Comment: I simply can't get EHCache to work - null pointer exception every time. I've seen a whole bunch of people with the same issue on the forums, but no answers at all.
Works ok with RAMCache, but not really suitable here. Can't see Memcached in the extension list and commercial is out I'm afraid.
To be fair, I'm happy with the speed increase from the file solution I've implemented, I was just wondering if fileRead or include would be the way to go there.

Comment: @Henry, drives if they're local, if they're network attached, it's a toss up.  The main difference with an out-of-process cache is horizontal scalability, failover, and automatic item expiration.